# How to set framerate for video produced from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 225 images and want a 15 fps video I should get a 225/15=15 second video. I set 'r' to 15 but I only got 9 second video. What's wrong?

`subprocess.call([ 'ffmpeg', '-i', 'file%02d.png', '-r', '15', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'video_name.mp4' ])`

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg assigns a default framerate of 25 for inputs which don't have an inherent framerate. What the `-r 15` does is drop frames to match the output rate while preserving timestamps of retained frames.

You need to set the input's framerate.

`subprocess.call([ 'ffmpeg', '-framerate', '15', '-i', 'file%02d.png', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'video_name.mp4' ]`

Comment: I still only got a 9s video. Should I be setting '-r' to something as well?

Comment: No. Share full log.