# webm files created with ffmpeg are too long

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, webm

I have a folder of exactly 300 images in png format (labelled `1.png`, `2.png`, ..., `300.png`), which I'm trying to convert to a video. I would like the video to be in the webm format, but there seems to be an issue:

using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i ./frames/%d.png -frames:v 300 -r 30 out.webm
```

does generate an `out.webm` file, and, according to `ffprobe -select_streams v -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames,r_frame_rate out.webm` (which is presumably quite an inefficient way to get that information, but that's besides the point), it does contain 300 frames and has a framerate of exactly `30/1`, however, instead of the expected exactly 10 seconds (from 300 frames being played at 30 fps), the video lasts slightly longer (about 12 seconds).
This discrepancy does seem to scale up with video length; 900 frames being converted to a video the same way and with the same frame rate yield a 36 (instead of 30) second video.

For testing, I also tried generating an mp4 file instead of a webm one, with the following command (exact same as above, but `out.mp4` instead of `out.webm`), and that worked exactly as expected, `out.mp4` was a 10-second long video.

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i ./frames/%d.png -frames:v 100 -r 30 out.mp4
```

How do I fix this? is my ffmpeg command off or is this a bug within the tool?

Comment: how long does it play for? do you have 12 seconds of audio? if you do `ffprobe -show_frames out.webm` you can probably figure out what is going on

Comment: i am not adding any audio - it does play for 12 seconds instead of the expected 10, that's what I meant, sorry if that was a bit unclear - I'll try the ffprobe command, thank you

Comment: so, i might have misunderstood what you specifically wanted me to look at, but i did a bit of testing on `ffprobe -show_frames out.webm`'s output via python, and it seems that it does show exactly 300 frames - since the frame rate does seem to be 30 fps though, how come the video is 12, not 10, seconds long?

Comment: try moving `-r 30` to in front of `-i` argument

Comment: @kesh wow that seems to have fixed it, thank you very much! can you make that an answer so I can accept it? (admittedly I'm also quite curious about why it works whereas the other order does not)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65085350/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation ( https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html ) has an example:

> For creating a video from many images: ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12
> -i foo-%03d.jpeg -s WxH foo.avi

and

> To force the frame rate of the input file (valid for raw formats only)
> to 1 fps and the frame rate of the output file to 24 fps: ffmpeg -r 1
> -i input.m2v -r 24 output.avi

and also

> As an input option, ignore any timestamps stored in the file and
> instead generate timestamps assuming constant frame rate fps. This is
> not the same as the -framerate option used for some input formats like
> image2 or v4l2 (it used to be the same in older versions of FFmpeg).
> If in doubt use -framerate instead of the input option -r.

For your case result:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i ./frames/%d.png output.webm
```